# Finding the most common terms in my Solr collection

Tags: solr, lucene, information-retrieval, stop-words

I need to identify potential stopwords in my Solr collection. Is it possible to find those terms which have the highest document frequency in my collection (or at least in a given shard)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [HighFreqTerms](http://lucene.apache.org/core//4_5_0/misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/HighFreqTerms.html), like:

```
TermStats[] stats = HighFreqTerms.gethighFreqTerms(reader, 10, "myContentField", new HighFreqTerms.DocFreqComparator());
for (TermStats stat : stats) {
    System.out.println(stat.termtext.utf8ToString() + ",   docfreq:" + stat.docFreq);
    //Or whatever else you want to do with them...
}
```

[Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) also prominently displays the most common terms.

Answer (score 0):

As you already set up Solr, use TermsComponent to get the term frequencies for any given field:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

If you have a default search field, (which is the destination of your copied field), it should give you the frequencies across all fields.